# Resultado calculado por evento click- en otra pagina html

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un botón en una página HTML que me va sumando cada vez que hago clic en él y quiero que ese resultado se refleje en otra página web al mismo tiempo con JavaScript, la segunda página se encuentra en el mismo cliente y navegador. ¿se puede hacer esto?

Comment: Hola, creo que es posible, agrega el código que tienes para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: con WebSockets.